# Eval() display custom value if null

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, eval

```
<td>
    <asp:Label ID="TypeOfPaintingLabel" runat="server"
               Text='<%# Eval("TypeOfPainting") %>' />
</td>
```

Does anyone know how this works? I want to display `"NA"` if there is no value provided to `TypeOfPainting`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

by creating a `public method` You can complete this task very easily like

```
public string testbind(object myvalue)
{
  if (myvalue == null)
  {
     return "NA value";
  }

  return myValue.ToString();
}
```

Label Code:

```
<asp:Label ID="TypeOfPaintingLabel" Text='<%# testbind(Eval("TypeOfPainting")) %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

Or you may use

```
<%#(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("TypeOfPainting").ToString()) ? "NA" : Eval("TypeOfPainting"))%>
```

You have to follow this type of scenarion.

Hope it works.

Comment: It work on the 2nd 1.
<%#(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("TypeOfPainting").ToString()) ? "NA" : Eval("TypeOfPainting"))%>

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 3):

Your control is `runat="server"` Why dont you control the value in codebehind?

```
If (string.IsNullOrEmpty(TypeofPaintingValue))
{
  TypeofPainting.Text="NA";
}
```

Comment: Yeah I typed fast as hell. Thanks @DimitarDimitrov. Corrected

Answer (score 2):

Well you can try to do something like:

```
<%#(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("TypeOfPainting").ToString()) ? "NA" : Eval("TypeOfPainting"))%>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set this things from database side also

```
ISNULL(TypeOfPainting,'NA') AS TypeOfPainting
```

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to  do it in `SQL` only:

using `ISNULL(expression, value_if_expression_is_null)`
or

```
COALESCE(expression, expression2, expression3)
```

example :

```
SELECT
  Name, DOB,
  (CASE WHEN Address1 IS NULL THEN 'NA' ELSE Address1 END) AS Address1,
  (CASE WHEN Address2 IS NULL THEN 'NA' ELSE Address2 END) AS Address2,
  ...
FROM Users
```

or

```
SELECT 
  Name, DOB, Address1, 
  coalesce(Address2,'NA'), coalesce(City,'NA'), 
  coalesce(State,'NA'), coalesce(Zip,'NA')
FROM Users
```